# How to make gRPC calls from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to access a gRPC service from Google Sheets and I know I can do a HTTP/JSON call from apps script and then translate that at the server side but I would like to know if there is an option to make a gRPC call directly,

Answer (score 1):

#### gRPC is not supported in Apps Script or Sheets

I don't see any feature requests for this, so if you want to see that feature, you would need to file a feature request using this template:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113

Adding in as much detail, context and business justification will help a lot to get it noticed.

Comment: Does "gRPC is not supported in Apps Script or Sheets" mean that grpc-web is not supported either?

Comment: Its slightly different but its not supported either I'm afraid

Comment: We were able to make gRPC calls in an MS Excel Web-Addins using grpc-web. Do you perhaps have more details on why grpc-web is not supported in Apps Script? Here is a link to the above implementation https://github.com/alis-x/upwork-msoffice/tree/main/excel/src/functions

Comment: @JanKrynauw Unfortunately, the link is broken. Would you kindly create a gist with your implementation? ‍♂️